# Where to store a piece of important data (away from users) that will be backed up by itunes

Tags: ios, backup, itunes

I am currently making an app and there is an important piece of information I need to store. The user can make a one time in-app purchase.

My question is, what is the apple recommended or approved method for storing this?

No. 1 is most important to me.  For example imagine the user can purchase 10 lives.  After his purchase he will use some of them so imagine he now has a balance of 5.  Where should this number be stored.

The issues or thoughts or random ideas I have as a result of reading things are;

- if its saved in a simple file then a jailbreaker can just go in an
  edit the file.
- if its saved in an encrypted file I think I have extra issues with my
  app/Apple/certain countries because I am using encryption.
- what happens when the user accidentally removes the app. He cannot
  restore his purchases as its a one time purchase
- should I be and how should this important piece of information be
  backed up on a sync
- how do I ensure this information is saved as part of a backup.

Comment: Better store the IAP details on your server and write an API that the app could consume. Why to worry about backup and all that?

Comment: Thanks, but I dont have a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure there is one answer to this problem.  In my case I save the information in the keychain.  Other iOS SDKs such as Amazon's or Facebook's do the same thing as far as I can see.